# Unhandled exception in lookup [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:

Tags: java, weblogic, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I need help!

I tryed This so far.....

Here is my ejb code:

```
package ejb30.session;
import java.util.*; 
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

//@Stateless
@Stateless(mappedName="Time")  
public class TimeServiceBean implements TimeService {
   public String getTime() { 
     Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     fmt.format("%tr", cal);
     return fmt.toString();   
  } 

}
```

Here is my ejb client code:

```
package ejb30.client;

import javax.naming.*;
import ejb30.session.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

       InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

       // glassfish version:
       // TimeService timeService = (TimeService) ctx.lookup("ejb30.session.TimeService");

       // weblogic version:      
       TimeService timeService = (TimeService) ctx.lookup("Time#ejb30.session.TimeService");

       String time = timeService.getTime();
       System.out.println("Time is: " + time);
    }
}
```

I am using weblogic 12.2 and I started my weblogic server:
When I called client code I get the following error:

```
run-client:
     [java] May 07, 2017 10:46:58 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0 read_value
     [java] WARNING: "IOP00810211: (MARSHAL) Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream"
     [java] org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.valuehandlerReadException(ORBUtilSystemException.java:7004)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1010)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:844)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:838)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:828)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream.java:287)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Utility.readAbstractAndNarrow(Utility.java:964)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2030)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:844)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:267)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TCUtility.unmarshalIn(TCUtility.java:285)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.read_value(AnyImpl.java:590)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:704)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(CDRInputStream.java:238)
     [java]     at weblogic.corba.cos.naming._NamingContextAnyStub.resolve_any(_NamingContextAnyStub.java:81)
     [java]     at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:227)
     [java]     at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:191)
     [java]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
     [java]     at ejb30.client.Client.main(Unknown Source)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ejb30.session.TimeServiceBean_9qy6tc_TimeServiceRIntf
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:1207)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
     [java]     at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.readObject(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:261)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
     [java]     ... 23 more
     [java]
     [java] Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Unhandled exception in lookup [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe]
     [java]     at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.Utils.wrapNamingException(Utils.java:83)
     [java]     at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:251)
     [java]     at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:191)
     [java]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
     [java]     at ejb30.client.Client.main(Unknown Source)
     [java] Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.valuehandlerReadException(ORBUtilSystemException.java:7004)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1010)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:844)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:838)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:828)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream.java:287)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Utility.readAbstractAndNarrow(Utility.java:964)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2030)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:844)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:267)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TCUtility.unmarshalIn(TCUtility.java:285)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.read_value(AnyImpl.java:590)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:704)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(CDRInputStream.java:238)
     [java]     at weblogic.corba.cos.naming._NamingContextAnyStub.resolve_any(_NamingContextAnyStub.java:81)
     [java]     at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:227)
     [java]     ... 3 more
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ejb30.session.TimeServiceBean_9qy6tc_TimeServiceRIntf
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [java]     at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:1207)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
     [java]     at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.readObject(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:261)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
     [java]     at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
     [java]     ... 23 more
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 16 seconds
```

C:\EJB3DeveloperGuide\tempCode\tempWeblogicCode\EJB3Chap02\weblogic10.3\lab1>

I need some clues in what couse the problem...

Comment: How are you loading your beans?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error when you load your TimeServiceBean class, if you read your stacktrace carefully, you will see that. Check the way your loading your beans